# Iterating over and accessing multiple maps at once (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, maps

I have a variety have maps that have the same keys, but different values - I'm trying to calculate the average value along each dimension of the map. For example, I may have three maps that have 3 keys - this number may change, as well as the number of keys.

```
var a = new Map ([["wordOne", 153], ["wordTwo", 24], ["wordThree", 73]]);
var b = new Map ([["wordOne", 346], ["wordTwo", 693], ["wordThree", 124]]);
var c = new Map ([["wordOne", 34], ["wordTwo", 4352], ["wordThree", 93]]);
```

I'm trying to replicate the equation below, so I can get an **average value** for that key from the 3 different maps that I have selected.

```
[(a_1 + b_1 + c_1)/3]
[(a_2 + b_2 + c_2)/3]
[(a_3 + b_3 + c_3)/3]
```

I then want to take the averages and store them in a new map, along with the key that the averages represent.

How can I create a for loop in JavaScript that iterates over a selection of maps and performs the averaging equation on each value for maps selected and store it in a new map with the same keys?

Comment: please add the wanted result of the given data.

Comment: I’m  not really after the result. What I want is to know how to iterate over multiple maps and their content, ready for the equation mentioned

Comment: ok, then where do you get `a_99` from?

Comment: It’s just an example that shows a map with 100 elements... my maps have thousands of elements

Comment: @JimmyNeedles it's not clear in your example if `a_99` is from a map with 100 values, or the first value of the 100th map. Your example makes it look like you want an array of the average of each individual map. To put it another way: it looks like `[(a_1 + b_1 + c_1)/3]` should be the average value of  `mapOne` but you're describing something different.

Comment: your question is quite unclear, what you like to achive. does `a` has somehting to do with the first map and `b` for the second, or does it denotes a key for the map as in `mapOne` and so on. please add an example with short data and what you like to get from.

Comment: Yeah, sorry guys - I agree. I’ve edited the question to make it clearer. It should be noted that I won’t just be using 3 maps, sometimes it will be 2,4, 5, 6 etc

Comment: If you're talking about Maps, why is there no single Map in the examples you've shown?

Comment: hm. ........ ..? really?

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like `(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)/3` rather than `(a_1 + b_1 + c_1)/3` It would really be easier if you would just post what you're starting with and the final desired result.

Comment: Nope, what I want is correct. I’m just explaining it poorly - i’ll rephrase the question

Comment: if we do not know, what is `a` or `b` and `0` and `1`, it could be everything. and the actual maps are not given. just some size of the maps ... but how are the data connected? via key? if so, you need to get the keys of a single map and access all other maps with it.

Comment: See edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average of each key you can first put all the maps in one array. This will make it possible to iterate over them. Then get a list of all the keys of one of the maps and iterate on that. This assumes the all the maps have the same keys.

```js
var a = new Map ([["wordOne", 153], ["wordTwo", 24], ["wordThree", 73]]);
var b = new Map ([["wordOne", 346], ["wordTwo", 693], ["wordThree", 124]]);
var c = new Map ([["wordOne", 34], ["wordTwo", 4352], ["wordThree", 93]]);
// make array of maps
let maps = [a, b, c];

// Average of each key across maps (i.e [average_a, average_b, average_c])
// map over all keys(), then average across the maps
let averages_across = [...maps[0].keys()].map(key => [key, maps.reduce((sum, map) => sum + map.get(key), 0)/maps.length])

console.log(averages_across)
// make a new map from this
let average_map = new Map(averages_across)
```

Comment: what is with the dots before `maps[0]`? `[...maps[0].keys()].map(key => [key, maps.reduce((sum, map) => sum + map.get(key), 0)/maps.length]);`

Comment: Hey @JimmyNeedles, `keys()` returns an iterator not an array and iterators don't have a `map()` function. So `[...maps[0].keys]` takes the iterator of from `keys()` and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)s it into an array which you can then call `map()` on.

Comment: Okay, interesting. Today is the first time I've come across `...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand but *accessing each value of each key on every iteration* could be one of these:

```js
var mapOne = new Map ([["a", 153], ["b", 24], ["c", 73]]);
var mapTwo = new Map ([["a", 346], ["b", 693], ["c", 124]]);
var mapThree = new Map ([["a", 34], ["b", 4352], ["c", 93]]);

//each key of all maps in each iteration. a+a+a/3 b+b+b/3... etc
mapThree.forEach((v,k)=>{

    console.log((mapOne.get(k)+mapTwo.get(k)+v)/3)

});


//the average of each map
[...[mapOne],...[mapTwo],...[mapThree]].forEach(m=>{

    var res = 0;

    mapThree.forEach((v,k)=>{// a+b+c/3 ... etc
    
        res += mapOne.get(k);
    
    })
    
    console.log(res/3)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript and Map methods.

```js
var mapOne = new Map ([ ["a", 153], ["b", 24], ["c", 73] ]);
var mapTwo = new Map ([ ["a", 346], ["b", 693], ["c", 124] ]);
var mapThree = new Map ([ ["a", 34], ["b", 4352], ["c", 93] ]);

function averageValuesKeyMaps ( ...maps )
{
  // Map for key => averages
  const averagesMap = new Map ();

  let 
    // Get the first map as a reference,
    mapRef = maps[ 0 ],
    // Get the size, assuming that each map is the same size
    size = mapRef.size,
    // Get the keys, assuming that every maps have those keys
    keys = maps[ 0 ].keys()

  // For each key in keys 
  for ( let key of keys )
  {
    // Get the average with each value of the current key for each map
    let average = maps.reduce( ( acc, map ) => acc + map.get( key ), 0 ) / size;
    
    // Set the key => average
    averagesMap.set( key, average );
  }

  // Return the new map of averages
  return averagesMap;
}

// Get the map of averages key values
let averagesMap = averageValuesKeyMaps( mapOne, mapTwo, mapThree );

// Usage example
for ( let [ key, average ] of averagesMap.entries() )
{ 
  // Do something with key or average
  console.log( key, average );
}
```